# DropboxSDK: unable to link; app isn't registered for correct URL scheme

Tags: ios, xcode, swift2, dropbox-api

I try to integrate Dropbox in my app. I use DropboxSDK 1.3.13. Sort of I make right but I get the error 
**DropboxSDK: unable to link; app isn't registered for correct URL scheme (db-8915lo7r9ra91xr)**

My scheme 
[image]

[image]

```
 let appKey = "8915lo7r9ra91xr"

 let session = DBSession(appKey: appKey, appSecret: secret, root: kDBRootDropbox)
 DBSession.setSharedSession(session)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typo. The scheme needs to start with `db-`, not `dp-`.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone still facing this error even after updating pList file properly, You need to check once that whether your application's info.plist file is selected for your desired target or not.

It wasted a couple of hours of mine, hope that it will be helpful to others.

Answer (score 0):

Add proper URL schemes :

***please refer below screenshot ;***

[image]